# How to use in-memory data storing with JsonSystem (Itemscript JSON library)?

Tags: java, json, gwt

I am developing a GWT application in which I need to keep some state of application using `Itemscript JSON library's JsonSystem`.

As for the purpose I created a JsonSystem and put data inside it as follows:

```
GwtSystem.SYSTEM.put(GwtHttpConnector.CONFIG_URL, false);
JsonSystem system =  GwtSystem.SYSTEM;
system.put("state","state_value");
```

I want to know,
 - how long is this data will be available?
 - when ever I refresh my page these data will not be available, so I doubt is this the procedure to store data in-memory, if so what is the actual procedure?

references : https://code.google.com/p/itemscript/ [3rd feature] 
           : https://code.google.com/p/itemscript/wiki/GettingStartedGwtJava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it doesn't say on the project page but if it is a real in-memory database then you will lose the data once you refresh the page. Did you try it ?

If you want to keep the data between refreshes you can use `LocalStorage`. You have to [dump](https://code.google.com/p/itemscript/wiki/GettingStartedRESTfulJSONDatabase#Dump_and_load_parts_of_the_database) the `JsonSystem` convert to a `String` and store in `LocalStorage`.